# Check if Page=current user page via shortcode

Tags: shortcode, users

How can i develop a shortcode, which checks, if the current page is the page of the user, does something if it is and something else, if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are assigning a page to the user, however you can develop a short-code as following:

```
<?php

   function myFunction()
   {
       if({condition check})
       {
         /*do ur stuff */
       }
       else
       {
         /*do ur stuff */
       }
   }

   add_shortcode('your_shortocde_string', 'myFunction');

?>
```

Define the function in `functions.php`
You can call by using shortcode `[your_shortcode_string]`

I hope this will be helpful.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thats really helpful, thanks! :)
About the user page: I thought about checking the page slug, if it contains the nicename of the user.